# Can I make my own native methods in Java?

Tags: java, java-native-interface

Can I write my own C/C++ code and implement it in a native method in Java?
Suppose I want to develop some memory management application in Java, but I need some C/C++ functionality, then can I do it  ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, use the [Java Native Interface/JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), quite simple to use.

Alternatively, you could try the [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) third-party library that has a nicer API.